# how to access the laravel project after installation?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have installed the laravel 5 on my local machine.And made the changes in the database.php file in config folder.I have set my credential.Now I am accessing the folder `http://localhost/laravel/public/` but it displays html page with this content. `Whoops, looks like something went wrong`.What configuration should I set apart from this database.php so that it works fine.

Comment: Please provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely happen to you everytime you create a new Laravel project. The problem is that your webservice (apache/nginx) doesn't have read/write permissions for the storage folder. From the root of your installation perform a `chmod 777 -R ./storage` and that should get you to the welcome to Laravel screen you should expect for an installation, and from that point on you should now get the error reporting if you have debug mode set as true. If you are still having trouble, you may need to provide access to the `./public` folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can run laravel application when you have successfully installed in your machine, Add '/public' in url after root folder. Means you have installed app on www.firstlaravel.com and your root folder is 'first'.
So you can run app using like => www.firstlaravel.com/public